# Como ler várias linhas de um arquivo de texto (.txt) e armazená-las numa mesma variável?

Tags: java

Alguém tem uma ideia para me ajudar a extrair as linhas abaixo e que sempre se apresentam neste padrão?

```
Palavra1 (é sempre igual)
Linha a ser extraida, de tamanho variavel
Linha a ser extraida, de tamanho variavel
Linha a ser extraida, de tamanho variavel
Palavra2 (é sempre igual)

bla bla bla
bla bla bla

Palavra1 (é sempre igual)
Linha a ser extraida, de tamanho variavel
Linha a ser extraida, de tamanho variavel
Linha a ser extraida, de tamanho variavel
Palavra2 (é sempre igual)
```

As 3 linhas são partes da mesma informação que eu devo guardar em uma única variável e exibir ao usuário, mas que, na hora da conversão do arquivo, acabaram sendo jogadas em 2, 3 ou 4 linhas.

Segue o código que eu imaginei até aqui:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if(linha.startsWith("palavra1")){
    linha = arquivoEntrada.readLine() + 1; //pula a linha
    if(!linha.startsWith("palavra2")){ //minha condição de parada
        sb.append(linha + " "); //StringBuffer pra ir armazenando as linhas lidas
                                //como fazer o sistema pular a linha agora??????
    } else {

    }
    variavelQualquer = sb.toString();
}
```

Com esse código, eu só consigo pegar a primeira linha. Tentei com `while` em vez do segundo `if`, mas não funcionou.

Qualquer ajuda seria bem-vinda.

Comment: Você pode postar mais algum trecho do código? Acho que ajudaria entender o que está fazendo e propor algo mais próximo do que você precisa.

Comment: Resumidamente, eu tinha um arquivo PDF que foi convertido em txt. Meu trabalho é manipular via substring certas informações deste TXT gerado e, por fim, criar outro arquivo TXT final exibindo apenas as informações manipuladas. No caso, essas 3 ou mais linhas que eu ilustrei deveriam estar numa única linha (ou seja, elas são a informação que eu preciso), mas o conversor PDF p/ TXT acabou quebrando e jogando em várias linhas. Preciso agora, então, reuni-las novamente e jogar no TXT final como uma linha única. Espero que tenha ficado mais claro agora.

Comment: A ausência de pelo menos um ciclo me faz ver que só deverá mesmo ler a primeira linha.

Comment: @Cold, eu tentei usar o while, mas deu estouro de memória. De todo modo, o if deveria funcionar se minha lógica estivesse correta.

Comment: @bigown Minha lógica foi tentar trabalhar com a regularidade que me permite identificar o bloco de linhas de que eu preciso, e essa regularidade é a existência de uma mesma palavra antes dessas linhas e outra palavra depois dessas linhas. Quer dizer, as linhas que eu preciso estão sempre num bloco delimitado por 2 palavras que são sempre iguais.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro o seguinte:

```
...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
linha = arquivoEntrada.readLine();
do 
{
    if (linha.startsWith("Palavra1"))//verifica se começa pela Palavra e não
    {
        String linhaAux = arquivoEntrada.readLine();
        while (linhaAux != null && !linhaAux.startsWith("Palavra2"))
        {
            sb.append(linhaAux + " ");
            linhaAux = arquivoEntrada.readLine();
        }
    }
    linha = arquivoEntrada.readLine();
} while (linha != null)
...
```

Comment: sua ideia funcionou mais ou menos, mas o suficiente para que eu possa tentar caminhar sozinho. Não consigo dar upvote porque não tenho 15 pontos de reputação. De qualquer maneira, agradeço muito.

Comment: Sem makas. Me diz o que significa mais ou menos :) ?

Comment: Hehe, na verdade, funcionou. Ele concatenou as linhas como eu precisava. O "mais ou menos" fica por conta de ele ter retornado não apenas as linhas concatenadas, mas ter gerado várias linhas em branco entre cada uma das linhas concatenadas. Ainda tô tentando entender o porquê disso e eliminar essas linhas em branco. De qualquer maneira, as linhas que importam estão concatenadas e eu novamente lhe agradeço muito.

Comment: Linhas em branco? Hum. Não vejo como, ainda.